# What is using all of my memory on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, php, memory, memory-usage, virtual-memory

I keep getting alarms from Rackspace telling me that my memory usage is too high, but I can't seem to find the culprit.

I ran top SHIFT + M to see top output sorted by memory, and this is what I get (seems that php is running really high on memory if I'm correct):

[image: top]

Is it normal for PHP to be using this much memory? Is there anyway to trace why it is using so much memory?

Comment: Top isn't going to tell you anything about why a particular process is using memory. And what are you doing with PHP that it's running as Root?

Comment: You should look at the application that you are running. You failed to mention what that is, so it's impossible to say anything more.

Comment: What do you mean "the application that you are running"? I have a few wordpress sites on this machine and that is it

Comment: That doesn't look *that* abnormal for a php application. You might be able to free up some ram by tweaking some applications - mysql has a bunch of buffers (query buffer, innodb table buffer, etc) which will use less ram if made smaller. I'm tempted to suggest switching from httpd.prefork to httpd.worker, but that requires changing php versions to the thread safe version and I've never actually tried doing that to an in-production system.

Comment: Just to double check, can you look at /proc/meminfo to double check that you don't have a giant disk cache? It doesn't look like it but it doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: Did you install 300 different WordPress plugins, then? Something is eating up all that RAM; that's highly abnormal for a WordPress installation.

Comment: There are about 20 WP sites on this server

Comment: Then the hard part is figuring out which one of those 20 is the cause of the problem.